# how to config mock store

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

```js
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middlewares = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
const store = mockStore()
```

Comment: TypeError: (0 , _reduxMockStore.default) is not a function

Comment: thanks in advance to resolve this issue

Comment: Hi, please edit your post to format your code and question ;) If you don't, your post could be closed :/

Comment: Is any error? Please edit your post and add the error detail